# Sequence not working in Manipulate?

Tags: manipulate, sequence

I have a function that I would like to construct the `Manipulate` parameter list with `Sequence`. This is a simpler example but it has the same behaviour.

```
x[a_, b_, c_] := a + b + c
parmsForSlider = {{#, 5. *10^6}, 1.*10^6, 20.*10^6, 0.5*10^6} & /@ {a, b, c} ;
```

`parmsForSlider` has the list for items I need for `Manipulate`.  I can get the sequence in a fake function.

```
f[q, Sequence @@ parmsForSlider]
```

However, if I try this in manipulate it does not separate out `paramsForSlider` as it does for `f`.

```
Manipulate[AccountingForm[x[a, b, c], DigitBlock -> 3], Sequence @@ parmsForSlider]
```

Instead it gives the error:

*Manipulate::vsform: "Manipulate argument Sequence@@parmsForSlider does not have the correct form for a variable specification."*

However, if I type in the parameters and ranges it will work.

```
Manipulate[
  AccountingForm[x[a, b, c], DigitBlock -> 3], 
  {{a, 5. * 10^6}, 1. * 10^6, 20 * 10^6, 0.5 * 10^6}, 
  {{b, 5. * 10^6}, 1. * 10^6, 20 * 10^6, 0.5 * 10^6}, 
  {{c, 5. * 10^6}, 1. * 10^6, 20 * 10^6, 0.5 * 10^6}
]
```

Have I done something incorrectly?  I'm using 10.0.2 in Windows 8.1 64bit.

Comment: Try with `Evaluate[Sequence[...]]`. Looking for duplicate...

Comment: @kuba, I did not see your comment before my answer. sorry

Comment: @Algohi No need to, I failed to find proper duplicate anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Manipulate has Attributes `HoldAll`.

Try this:

```
Manipulate[AccountingForm[x[a, b, c], DigitBlock -> 3], 
 Evaluate[Sequence @@ parmsForSlider]]
```