# Generating Manipulate variables from a list of rules

Tags: manipulate, rule, sequence

I have the following list of rules:

```
minru = {"ksp" -> 0.3393, "pl" -> 0.3675, "qtz" -> 0.1628, 
         "hb" -> 0.0714552, "bi" -> 0.0476368, "sph" -> 0.006268, 
         "zrc" -> 0.000672, "ilm" -> 0.000168, "ap" -> 0.000348, 
         "aln" -> 0.000812, "cal" -> 0.002, "fl" -> 0.003}
```

I want to use this to make a `Manipulate`-able list as output. I want to turn the keys (rhs) into a set of variables and use the values (lhs) to define the range and initial parameters for the variables. I'm hoping to get a list of adjustable, normalised values within a manipulate frame with a slider for each input variable.

Here is the kind of thing I'm trying to achieve (minus the programatic variable definition):

```
Manipulate[
 Module[{sum, vars},
  sum = x + y + z;
  vars = {x/sum, y/sum, z/sum}],
    {{x, 0.33}, 0.001, 0.5, Appearance -> "Open"}, 
    {{y, 0.33}, 0.001, 0.5, Appearance -> "Open"}, 
    {{z, 0.33}, 0.001, 0.5, Appearance -> "Open"}]
```

[image]
[image]

What I've tried to far:

```
mantest[propru_] :=
 Manipulate[
  Module[{manvars, tot},
   manvars = ToExpression[propru[[All, 1]]];
   tot = Total[manvars];
   (#/tot) & /@ manvars
   ],
  Evaluate[Sequence @@ 
   ReplaceList[propru, 
    KeyValuePattern[{x_ -> y_}] :> 
             {{ToExpression[x], y}, y - 0.5 * y, y + 0.5 * y}]]
  ]
mantest[minru]
```

Alas, Mathematica says "no"...

[This question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/76893/sequence-not-working-in-manipulate) got me some of the way but the variable parameters (from lhs) still aren't working....

[image]

Any suggestions on how to do this? Do need to use `Hold` somewhere?

Comment: does this give what you need: `mantest[propru_] :=DynamicModule[{manvars=Symbol/@Keys[propru], values=Values@propru  },Manipulate[Evaluate@Normalize[manvars ,Total],Evaluate[Sequence@@({{##},(1-.5)#2,(1+.5)#2}&@@@Transpose[{manvars, values}])] ]];
mantest[minru]`?
`

Comment: Do you want to apply a function to all values like `Normalize[vars, Totla]` or do you want to be able to use them separately e.g. `ksp + aln`.

Comment: @kglr yes, that works nicely! If you have time, perhaps you should make it into an answer and perhaps explain why this works where my approach failed. Many Thanks!

Comment: @Kuba I not quite sure I understand. I'm aiming to perform a simple normalisation of the form `var_i / sum(var)`. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mantest[propru_] := DynamicModule[{manvars = Symbol /@ Keys[propru], 
 values = Values @ propru }, 
 Manipulate[Evaluate @ Normalize[manvars, Total],
 Evaluate[Sequence@@({{##}, (1-.5)#2, (1+.5)#2} & @@@ Transpose[{manvars, values}])]]];

mantest[minru]
```

[image]

Comment: Hopefully a quick follow question: how do I define the list so that i ca n use it as a dynamic list object in other contexts? i.e. How do I use the resulting dynamic list outside of the manipulate wrapper?